# Unable to get button text to change in SwiftUI when changing boolean value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I want to have a button that when clicked toggles a boolean and changes the text of the button. By using print statements I can confirm that the button is properly toggling the bool value but it is not changing the text of the button.

I have tried manually setting the bool default value to false and this does change the text but I am still unable to get it to change when toggled.

```
Button(action: {
                Variables.userTriangle.cupShooting = 7
                Variables.userTriangle.triangle[6].toggleStatus()
            }) {
                if !Variables.userTriangle.triangle[6].status {
                    Text("x")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                } else {
                    Text("7")
                        .font(.largeTitle)
                }
            }
```

When the button it tapped, I expect it to change the value of the text by changing the boolean value. I plan on having multiple of these buttons.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I believe the view is only built once and so it is not checking that if condition every time it changes...

What you can do is make your text a `@State` var and then when you change it it will update in the view automatically.

```
@State var someText = "x"

...

Button(action: {
                Variables.userTriangle.cupShooting = 7
                Variables.userTriangle.triangle[6].toggleStatus()
                if (Variables.userTriangle.triangle[6].status) {
                   self.someText = "7"
                } else {
                   self.someText = "x"
                }
            }) {
                Text(self.someText).font(.largeTitle)

            }
```

Comment: Thank you. I was able to get it to work using that method. However, I plan on having multiple buttons that have this behavior each with different text (~20) is there a more efficient way to do this other than creating variables for each one.

Comment: @ThomasBraun glad it worked, unfortunately I haven't played around with SwiftUI that much yet to know a better method of doing what you need.

Answer (score 1):

The simpler way would be:

```
Button(action: {
            Variables.userTriangle.cupShooting = 7
            Variables.userTriangle.triangle[6].toggleStatus()
        }) {
            Text(Variables.userTriangle.triangle[6].status ? "7" : "x")
        }
```

Comment: Sorry I am new to Xcode/SwiftUI. Does that format with the ? and : basically make it do two different things based off the value of a bool?

Comment: @ThomasBraun its a ternary operator, used in many languages - does the first thing if true and the thing after the `:` if false

Comment: Just want to let you know that I tried that method and it didn't work. I think it is because of what Quinn said in his response but SwiftUI is only built once so it doesn't recheck the status of the if condition. Still appreciate teaching me the ternary operator tho

Comment: Views declared in SwiftUI get redrawn every time value of variable marked as State, Binding or ObservedObject changes. To make it more efficient only elements whose look depends on those variables get redrawn. The problem I assume is with the way your array is declared.